# Ionic Application Crashes on Splash Screen iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

so I have built my ionic app in iOS but when I open it, it will immediately crash after showing the splash screen. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Do you use any of google services in the app? What plugins are you using?

Comment: I'm using firebase as db and using its authentication module. I deleted the phonegap push plugin as said in another post but it still crashes.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please add more details first.
Run: `ionic info`

Also share some of the code if possible.

Also for login are you using:

```
    this.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if(user){
});
```

Comment: ionic info:

cli packages: (C:\Users\malan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    Node : v6.11.2
    npm  : 3.10.10
    OS   : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro

Comment: ` const unsubscribe = angularFireAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged( user => {
        if (!user) {
          this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
          unsubscribe();
        } else { 
          if(user.emailVerified){
            this.rootPage = 'TabsPage';
            unsubscribe();
          }
          else{
            this.angularFireAuth.auth.signOut();
            this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
            unsubscribe();
          }
        }
      }); `

Comment: sorry im new to stackoverflow so I dont know how to format texts here

Comment: Quick question, why are you unsubscribing from the auth Observable? Are you only logging in quickly? You might need the auth state for realtime-database.